# Matching key in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following which works well for matching a key within a dictionary.

```
if mydict.__contains__('bananas'):
    print "found"
```

Is there a way to base the `if` on the logic that the string is *not* found

Comment: It seems you are asking for `if not mydict.__contains__('bananas')`?

Comment: don't use `__contains__`, use `in`

Comment: @felix001 By `index` you mean key right? If so we should change the question because an index can be interpreted like a list index

Comment: @jamylak, you give the right answer in comments. Content with huge reputation ? ;-)

Comment: @VinayakKolagi haha well that's not really the answer, just a coding tip since accessing special methods is usually discouraged. I did submit the answer but I deleted out of confusion since the question originally looked for an *index* but the OP actually meant key.

Comment: if not works well for me. Thanks for the clarification of keys and indexes.

Answer (score 8):

This is possible:

```
if "bananas" not in mydict:
    print "not found"
```

Comment: will that only look at the index`s ?

Comment: As you can read in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.contains), `__contains__` "return[s] the outcome of the test b in a". So in the case of a dictionary, `in` will look at `d.keys()`.

Comment: @Tichodroma Well it won't actually look at `d.keys()` since that returns a list, it will look at the keys of `d` however